# Image or icon on particular node output

Tags: nodes, media

Is there any way to replace image/icon for a particular node output ?

A simple Example:

I am getting input from user sucn as 
"is your car running in petrol or diesel ?" if he selects the diesel then in node output instead of displaying diesel it should display the Diesel icon which i provide.

Is there any module for that because i have several input like this..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your field is a reference field like node reference or term reference, then you can add an image field in the referenced entity for associating the image. Then in your node tpl file, you can load the referenced entity and print the image. If you do not want to write a custom tpl, then this can be done using the [Display Suite](http://www.drupal.org/project/ds) module. But unless you need Display Suite for other purposes, the tpl way is better.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a basic select field, an if/then in your node TPL file can display the icons based on the field value. Something like:

```
<?php 
if (!isset($node->field_petrol_diesel['und'][0]['value'])) { 
  if ($node->field_petrol_diesel['und'][0]['value']=='petrol') :
    print '<img src="/path/to/petrol-icon.png" />';   
  elseif ($node->field_petrol_diesel['und'][0]['value']=='diesel') :
    print '<img src="/path/to/diesel-icon.png" />';
  endif;
} ?>
```

The first IF checks to see if the field has a value. It then checks to see what the value is, and displays an icon accordingly. You would need to change the field name (field_petrol_diesel) and the icon paths to match your site.